# In the context of Beam Deflections If the moment curve has a discontinuity, how do we account for it in the slope and deflection curve?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, beam, solid-mechanics, deflection, bending

In reality if we load a beam within the elastic range of the material, it forms a curve that can be represented by a mathematical equation. But if the moment curve has a discontinuity it must mean that the slope at a point is undetermined. Or to put it in mathematical context $\lim_{x\to x_0^-} f'(x) \neq \lim_{x\to x_0^+} f'(x)$. In this case is there a sharp corner on the beam, a cusp or anything ?Any intuition that jogs the visual imagination is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If i get what you mean correctly, moment diagram can and does have discontinuity under certain loading, without any issues. For example a simply supported beam with a moment applyed at mid span, see tthe diagram below.
If this doesn't address your quastion, let me know.

.

[image: moment]

Comment: Nice answer, but I think it stops where it gets interesting. It would be nice to also show the slope and deflection curve. The slope is the integral of the moment, so the moment discontinuity becomes a slope cusp. The deflection is the integral of the slope, so the slope cusp becomes a smooth line in the deflection curve. This proves that beams should not have cusps. If yours does, worry!